# Why are Window Captions Black and Buttons frameless sometimes during debugging

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, debugging, windows-xp

When debugging my Win32 Applications windows and dialogs sometimes (rarely) do not appear in the chosen Windows scheme, but rather reduced or broken:

[image]

The Window captions are all black (instead of blue or silver) and without any shadow. The Buttons doe not have any Button shape ("Abbrechen" in the screen shot). The black bar at the lower half is a windows progress bar. It doesn't show any progress when this happens.

The screen shot (details in the center greyed out) was taken from a 64-Bit application debugged under Visual Studio 2010 on XP SP3 x64 and a 10 GB machine. The was plenty of RAM (some GB) spare.

Does anyone have a clue for the reason? I never do non-client area drawing or something.

**EDIT:** The symptom only occurs when the Visual Studio Debugger has been attached to the program. But even when the application has been detached from the debugger the problem remains. It does not occur when starting the program without debugging.

Comment: Is this a C# or C++ app?

Comment: This is a Win32 unmanaged C++ application.

Comment: I've never seen black areas like that in MFC apps during debug, especially in the non-client area (the part you have with caption "waugs wird gelesen").  That part is normally rendered by Windows itself, not MFC or by your code. That is why I wonder if you are using some "fancy" theme stuff.

Comment: This is NOT a MFC Project. Its a win32 C++ Project. We only make Win32 API calls. All classes are custom made.

Comment: Do your C++ Classes have some funky custom non-client paint handlers? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145212(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: No: As mentioned in the post "I never do non-client area drawing".

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two possibilities.

1. You use some other "theme engine" than the XP native, for example Clearlooks, etc. These engines may not always comply with all thing debuggers want, they may leave their message pump unpumped on some implicitly assumed (in debugger) point, and then the drawing just stalls. Same thing often happens when using some virtual desktop manager on windows, windows window manager is simply too hardwired..
2. Even 32bit programs in 32bit windows may run out of handles, this often results in windows starting being rendered with "Fixedsys" font. Your application shows symptoms only for Theme handled portions, which kind of indicates the possibility nr.1 again.

Try inspecting relevant windows with WinSpy and Process Explorer, unreasonable amounts of allocated resources may hint on what kind starvation is going on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i thought about such possibilities too. The problem happen only sometimes during program startup. Very unlikely that there is a shortage of GDI Handles - but ill check that. I do not use a different theme engine as well.

Comment: @RED SOFT ADAIR try debugging the program (and starting with) windbg. We once had our program crashing because Logitech SetPoint software injected some key monitoring dll while our program was starting and it messed up (probably stack) in a way our (very old) login system couldn't handle. windbg shows fairly obviously what things get loaded (showed more clearly than VS's Modules view).

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed SP1 for Visual Studio 2010? I haven't had this problem yet, but know that SP1 fixed a lot of problems with VS2010.

The other thing I do know is that WinXP x64 (which is still sp2 and not 3 btw) doesn't always play nice. It's not as well supported as the x86 version. Win Vista and 7 x64 allows for much smoother operation. (I have had some bad experiences with XP x64 myself)

Comment: Yes i have SP1 installed for VC 2010. Thats not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We encounter this kind of trouble. In fact it was due to our antivurus (not sure but I think it was McAfee Viruscan at the moment).

Comment: Did you see similar behavior? Missing GUI-Elements, reduced fonts etc.?

Comment: Yes exactly. We spent much time instrumenting our code (written in .NET). Finaly we build a simple Windows Form program with an entry field and a button, when the problem occured the button of the simple program disapeared. Once the antivirus disabled it's never happened again. Perhaps it's not your case, but just test it.

Answer (score 0):

To enforce visual styles in your application make sure to call it before you run your window, like this:

```
static void Main()  
{  
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();  
    Application.Run(new Form1());  
}
```

I've had the same problem happened before, particularly when using 3rd party components that use their own styling methods like Infragistics or ComponentOne

Comment: RedSoft is talking about Win32 and not .NET. You have posted a C# answer.

Comment: To be fair, the OP didn't actually tell us that till just recently, long after Michel tried to help.  I wish that there was a specific downvote-for-not-trying-to-tag-my-question-with-languages feature.

Answer (score 0):

I read about such symptoms (a while ago) so i googled it again and found the forum.
There seems to be an issue with some NVIDIA-drivers on WinXP-64. Also some people could get rid of the problem by reducing hardware-accelaration.

You might read the following forum (5 pages) yourself and decide if it applies to your situation.

http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=67608